# HTML5 / CSS issue

Tags: css

Maybe I'm just not seeing but I have an H2 tag that is taking on the properties of a parent outside the parent that I want it to follow. Does that make sense?
Here's what I mean. Look at the CSS:

```
#featured-products h2 {
    background: url(/clients/kettle-pizza/images/featured-products-bg.png) repeat-x;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    hight: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

and then:

```
.featured h2{ 
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #181d1f;
    font-size: 20px; 
    background:none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

when I use the H2 with the featured class the style form the featured-products gets used instead.
Here's the code for the index page

```
<div id="featured-products" class="container_12">
 <h2>featured products</h2>
 <div class="featured grid_4">
 <img src="/clients/kettle-pizza/images/kettle-pic.png" alt="Kettle-Pizza">
 <h2>22.5” Basic Kit</h2>
 <p>Text removed ....</p>
 </div>
 <div class="featured grid_4">
 <img src="/clients/kettle-pizza/images/kettle-pic.png" alt="Kettle-Pizza">
 <h2>22.5” Basic Kit</h2>
 <p>Text removed ....</p>
 </div>
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's the page if you want a visual. The 22.5" headings should not have a background
    http://northshorewebdesign.net/clients/kettle-pizza/

Comment: Suggestion for improving this question: the title isn't very specific. It'd be better if it were changed to something like "Why are my headers receiving the CSS styles from the parent element instead of the styles for the class I assigned to them?"

Answer (score 3):

There's a set of rules that governs specificity of CSS selectors. It should suffice to say that your `#featured-products h2` selector carries more weight than the `.featured h2` selector does, so the latter is being overridden by the former:

[image: Screencap of Webkit Inspector]

You can solve this in a number of ways, and the typical way to solve an issue of this kind is by making the latter rule more specific:

```
#featured-products .featured h2 {
  ...
}
```

In your case, though, this can be solved more simply and in a way that is more performant: use the *direct descendent selector* (`>`) on the first selector to avoid targeting the more-deeply nested element:

```
#featured-products > h2 {
  ...
}
```

Lastly, if changing your selectors was going to introduce a lot of problems for your stylesheet, you could use the `!important` declaration to prevent the more specific selectors properties from overriding one or more less-specific properties:

```
.featured h2 {
  background: white !important;
}
```

Comment: What is IE6? Ohhh, yeah, it doesn't work on Commodore 64 either. ;)

Comment: If you're a web developer and you don't have to worry about IE6, I envy you.

Comment: I haven't worried about IE6 for over 2 years. I haven't ever been fired for it yet. Just refuse to work with it and your boss will either fire you (doubtful) or find someone else who will. My argument is always that if someone cares so little about their experience that they are still using IE6 they won't care that a website looks like shit or is nearly unusable.

Comment: In the corporate sector many users are tied to IE6 by their admins.  It's not their choice.  I work in the corporate sector, and the sites and applications I work on have to work in that environment.

Comment: That's only the case so long as it's easy. If developers/admins/techies quit working with it (even governments are ahead of y'all), it'll be less easy to just stick with it. And if you don't like what you work on, it makes sense to go find something that you do. There are lots of interesting development jobs if you're willing to go and get them. With >40k rep, that's a rather large stick to get the attention of a company you might wanna work at. ;)

Comment: @RichieHindle let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2115/discussion-between-coreyward-and-richiehindle)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the id-based rule is more specific than the class-based rule, and hence takes precedence.  You need to make the class-based rule more specific, eg.:

```
#featured-products .featured h2 { 
    ...
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ehuPG/ for a simplified working example.

Answer (score 1):

Even better - throw away all yer current code, and code it up right:

http://jsfiddle.net/c6GnH

here is the html:

```
<div id="featured-products" class="container_12">
    <h2>featured products</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://northshorewebdesign.net/clients/kettle-pizza/images/kettle-pic.png" alt="Kettle-Pizza">
            <span>22.5" Basic Kit</span>
            <p>The Basic kit for 22.5includes USA made with 304 grade stainless steel KettlePizza insert, hi-temp thermometer, realwood handles w/ stainless hardware and a 15" aluminum pizza pan.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://northshorewebdesign.net/clients/kettle-pizza/images/kettle-pic.png" alt="Kettle-Pizza">
            <span>22.5" Basic Kit</span>
            <p>The Basic kit for 22.5includes USA made with 304 grade stainless steel KettlePizza insert, hi-temp thermometer, realwood handles w/ stainless hardware and a 15" aluminum pizza pan.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://northshorewebdesign.net/clients/kettle-pizza/images/kettle-pic.png" alt="Kettle-Pizza">
            <span>22.5" Basic Kit</span>
            <p>The Basic kit for 22.5includes USA made with 304 grade stainless steel KettlePizza insert, hi-temp thermometer, realwood handles w/ stainless hardware and a 15" aluminum pizza pan.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is the css:

```
#featured-products {
border:1px solid #bc4314;
width:958px;
display:block;
height:371px;
}

#featured-products h2 {
background: url(http://northshorewebdesign.net/clients/kettle-pizza/images/featured-products-bg.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-left: 25px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#featured-products ul {
display:bock;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
float:left;
width:956px;
list-style-type:none;
}
#featured-products ul li {
display:bock;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
float:left;
width:290px;
padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
text-align:center;
list-style-type:none;
}
#featured-products ul li img {
border:2px solid #f19720;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
#featured-products ul li span{
display:block;
clear:both;
font-weight:bold;
color: #181D1F;
font-size: 20px;
margin-bottom:8px;
}
#featured-products ul li p{
text-align:left;
padding:0px 10px 10px 10px;
color: #181D1F;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 22px;
}
```

This is much cleaner, and easier to read. Let me know if you have any questions, and gladly answer what i did.

Comment: Please take note how there is only 1 classname and 1 ID being used in my code